# Getting import error while running this code

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

Running [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxvna.png) in jupyter notebook from anaconda distribution.I have installed `gobject-introspection`,`pygobject` packages in anaconda. Getting this import error while running the code. Any kinds of help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    win = Gtk.Window()
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show()
    Gtk.main()

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-87-c31ab9206da1> in <module>
    ----> 1 import gi
          2 gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
          3 from gi.repository import Gtk
          4 
          5 win = Gtk.Window()

          ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py in <module>
          40 
          41 
          ---> 42 from . import _gi
          43 from ._gi import _API
          44 from ._gi import Repository

          ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. In order for us to best help you, please see this link on how to post a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Particularly see the note about posting code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the required things? I'm not sure this is what you mean, but maybe this can help you:

Installing the system provided PyGObject:

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute `sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0`
3. Change the directory to where your hello.py script can be found (e.g. `cd Desktop`)
4. Run `python3 ???.py`

Installing from PyPI with pip:

1. Open a terminal and enter your virtual environment
2. Execute `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0` to install the build dependencies and GTK
3. Execute `pip3 install pycairo` to build and install Pycairo
4. Execute `pip3 install PyGObject` to build and install PyGObject
5. Change the working directory to where your `???.py` script can be found
6. Run `python3 ???.py`